# How to set "setOnEditorActionListener" to a EditText in ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've used this code to place a collapsible `View (EditText)` in `ActionBarSherlock`:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = false;

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    return true;
}
```

When I try to set `setOnEditorActionListener` on the view (by its id), the app crashes:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch(v.getText().toString(), 3);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I need to have a `SearchField` in `ActionBar` and perform a search when user presses "Search" key on keyboard, but I don't know how to bind the `setOnEditorActionListener` to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `R.id.search` is inside your `R.layout.collapsible_edittext` layout? Where are you calling `findViewById()` from? For example, are you calling it in `onCreate()` or `onResume()`? Are you sure that the menu has been created at this point?

I would suggest including it inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. Something like this may work:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    boolean isLight = false;
    int menuItemId = 
        menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.ic_search)
            .setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS |
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW)
            .getItemId();
    EditText editText =
        (EditText) menu.findItem(menuItemId).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.search);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(...);
}
```

The other option would be to inflate the view and attach the listener before calling `MenuItem.setActionView(actionView)`.

(By the way, it is helpful to include the exception and stack trace, if you would like people to determine the cause of a crash.)

Comment: same as before, crashes the app, I've provided the code and LogCat output below.

Comment: Your method worked just fine, that was something else crashing the app, i don't what !?, Thanks